# How to fix a build error on webpack that is caused by }<

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

I'm running webpack-dev-server, and every time I use curly braces inside of an html tag, webpack shows an error.

[image]

It doesn't show the error message if I put a space between the closing curly brace "}" and greater than sign "<".

```
<div>{this.state.what} </div>
```

I have installed below dependencies:

```
  "@babel/core": "^7.4.0",
  "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.4.0",
  "@babel/polyfill": "^7.4.3",
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.2",
  "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
  "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
  "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
```

I don't want to put space between } and <
Any solution?

Comment: You can use simply "create-react-app" dev server. Why you need your own structure? Also you can check the boilerplates on github. There are many boilerplates on github to help you how you can setup your config or to do your own structure.

Comment: @Mustafa Thanks for your tip. This is my company work, and our app is not built with create-react-app...

Comment: try to upgrade all babel-packages versions to latest. most of them should be 7.4.4 now.